# Packaging and installing a python cli application with virtual environment (preferably pipenv)

Tags: python, deployment, pipenv

I grasp the concept of using virtual environments for developing projects. During development, it is great to be assured I won't break anything by adding/switching dependent packages and their versions like there's no tomorrow. What I cannot wrap my head around (and haven't seen a complete/comprehensible tutorial or documentation after watching and reading dozens of them) is how to apply that concept when pushing stuff to production.

But how do I make the complete product not break anything when installed? Building it and simply installing it with pip will still put it into the global site-packages and when it installs its dependencies, other apps might break when over-updating dependent package versions. So I guess besides developing in a virtual environment, I also have to deploy it to a virtual environment.

Let's suppose I develop an app in a pipenv-created virtual environment, and now that it is finished, I want to create a built distribution that I can deploy in production. How do I do that build so that it will install "properly"? Leaving all the risky stuff out of the requirements.txt will make it likely that pip probably won't screw things up for the other deployed products.

It also makes sure the app definitely won't work out of the box (I also noticed that a simple `py -m build` won't add the pipfile and pipfile.lock to the built distribution, but I guess that can be cured by adding them to the manifest.in). And I won't be able to use the pipfiles, as they won't be deployed when pip installs the packages, therefore pipenv won't have a clue about the required packages, as they should be removed from the requirements file (to avoid littering, in case someone tries to do it with pip instead of pipenv). Also installing with pip would create the entry points pointing to the modules in the non-virtual-environmented site-packages, so even if the dependencies were pushed into a virtual environment, the entry points would not see them.

On the other hand, if I try to install the app from the built distribution using pipenv, so that it will go straight into a virtual environment, the entry points will not be put into a location that is on the path, meaning that I'd have to manually add new paths every time there's a deployment (and I still have no idea if pipenv will have access or will use the pipfile.lock in the built distribution). Besides, will that entry point run in the environment if it is not activated first?

Am I seeing/understanding these things clearly? Is it even possible to install something from a built distribution this way? Or am I on a completely wrong track and I miss something critical? What is the proper way to deploy a built application into production while keeping other products intact?